# Text color of textfield in Sencha touch is not reflecting on Android devices

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am using a textfield in sencha touch view and setting the color to white but it is not taking white color and overriding default black color. How can I change the css to reflect it.

```
xtype : 'textfield',
        name : 'subject',
        id : 'interactionSubjectText',
        clearIcon : true,
        cls : 'ml',
        inputCls : 'textColor',
```

Comment: So did you find the fix?

Answer (score 1):

To change the colour on an android device you have to use the -webkit-text-fill-color css parameter.

In your case your css file should contain the following class:

```
.ml {-webkit-text-fill-color: red;}
```

There is a link on a sencha touch 2 forum where I took this solution:
[sencha touch forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226480-Problem-with-change-of-text-color-in-a-textfield-dynamically-in-android-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the text field, apply the white color to that class with important property. Sure it will work.